# How to get from Stansted Airport to Kings Cross London after midnight?

Tags: airport-transfer, london, stn

Besides Taxi, how can i get from Stansted Airport to Kings Cross London after 12am? As I will arrive Stansted from Pisa at 11:30pm that late.  I have checked the national rail website, it guides me to take train to Liverpool street, followed by tube to Kings cross (leaving at 01:21). However, the last tube I checked on the tube website is 00:48. It's so confusing.

Comment: What's your actual destination? The station, a hotel, something else... ?

Comment: It isn't confusing. National rail add an extra amount of time to transfer between national rail and tube and vice versa, as people might have luggage and maybe also unfamiliar with London's transport network and might need help.

Comment: depending on the airline it may take you hours before you get out of the airport!   By that time there may not be any trains into London.   Maybe pay a bit more for your flight so as to arrive at a better time.

Answer (score 7):

One option would be to take [easy bus](https://www.easybus.com/en/routes/london-stansted/) from the airport to Baker street, London:

[image: easyBus timetable]

From there you can take the Route Bus N205 from Stop D towards Stratford International. Visit [Transport for London](https://tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/) to see all you options to getting from Baker Street to King Cross.

Answer (score 5):

There is a night bus from Liverpool Street to Kings Cross [N205](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/gettingaround/maps/buses/tfl-bus-map/text/routeinfo.aspx?q=N205&r=N205&rn=1), so you can get to Liverpool Street with a train or a bus, and then take this bus. Also, there is a taxi stand near Liverpool Street station, it should be reasonably easy to find a black cab there, it is not far from there (around 3 miles), so the cost should be <£15. If nothing else works, it is 50 min walk according to Google maps.

Comment: Erm walking for at midnight in a city like London for someone who's not familiar is not good advice. Not to mention tugging your luggage all the way.

Comment: @Recc, I wouldn't do it myself, but different people have different preferences and different luggage...

Answer (score 4):

The [National Rail website](http://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/) says:

> TRANSFER  01:21    London Liverpool Street [LST]  London Kings Cross [KGX] 
>   01:57        0h 36m
>
> During times when the London Underground Network is closed customers are advised to use either Taxis or the Night Bus Network to continue their journey.

If you use the [TfL journey planner](http://journeyplanner.tfl.gov.uk/) it advises taking the 242 to City Thameslink and then the N63.  If you would prefer a single bus (saves money and is probably more reliable) you can replan the journey to minimise changes; this gives the N205 which runs every half hour.

From 2015 you will be able to make this journey on the [Night Tube](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/corporate/projectsandschemes/28868.aspx), taking the Central Line to change at Holborn and then the Piccadilly Line to Kings Cross.

Answer (score 2):

From Stanstead to Liverpool Street you have it covered already, and once you are in at Liverpool Street, yeas 205 Bus all day/all night - straight to Kings Cross.
When you are in London and need to check any travel arrangements, got to Transprot For London, http://journeyplanner.tfl.gov.uk/ this will save you a lot of time, there is also transit routes in google maps which are linked to the TFL data so either are good when you are on the go. Make sure you don't spend too much time underground, you will defo cut down lots of journey times by walking or getting the bus, taxis are expensive too. Oh and get an OYSTER card if you don't have one already otherwise you'll pay lots more to travel.

Answer (score 1):

How about some google maps magic?

https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir/Stansted+Airport,+Enterprise+House,+Bassingbourn+Rd,+Stansted,+Essex+CM24+1QW,+United+Kingdom/Kings+Cross,+London,+UK/@51.7414461,0.0346203,10z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m18!4m17!1m5!1m1!1s0x487604b8a52a1bb7:0x30a4d0976b352648!2m2!1d0.238953!2d51.885402!1m5!1m1!1s0x48761b10c73c4dcd:0x616f11fed05d6bb9!2m2!1d-0.1223684!2d51.5335479!2m3!6e4!7e2!8j1393635600!3e3

Comment: How about a post containing more than 6 words and a link?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  The link is very useful, showing the public transport, trains and night buses, but we do like a bit more detail in answers - the idea being that if the site you've linked to changes, the answer is still useful.  So perhaps you could update your answer with the transport options.

Comment: Give a man a fish.....